# How to extract cover art in C#/.NET using MediaInfo library?

Tags: c#

I am trying to extract the cover art (or multiple pieces when present) from media files (not limited to, but in particular, audio files) using MediaInfo library (DLL v23.09) in C#/.NET. The official DLL library download includes a wrapper class to invoke the function calls from within C#/.NET.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
MediaInfo mi = new MediaInfo();
mi.Open(filePath);
mi.Option("Complete"); // Same result even with mi.Option("Complete", "1");
string base64data = mi.Get(StreamKind.General, 0, "Cover_Data"); // Same result also with stream ID = 1 or 2 for example
```

That should have returned the cover art as a `Base64` encoded `string` but the returned stream was empty.

Incidentally, querying the container for existing cover art with: `mi.Get(StreamKind.General, 0, "Cover")` actually returns "Yes / Yes", which is correct because the file (MPEG-4/M4A) does indeed contain 2 embedded covers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediaInfo does not provide the cover data by default (it is huge and not used by a lot of people) so you need to add an option:

```
mi.Option("Cover_Data", "base64");
```

before opening the file.

Jérôme, developer of MediaInfo.

Comment: Thank you Jerome, I had tried this before per your suggestion to user Lord_Mulder on another forum but I used `mi.Option("Cover_Data", "base64")` after `Open` rather than before. Now this seems to change things a bit as I am getting a response back, but converting the `base64` stream to a `byte[]` is failing with the following message: `The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.`

Comment: I'm also not sure if and how I can extract multiple cover art pieces when more than one exists. Also not sure if this is related to the conversion error mentioned in my previous comment. Am I receiving multiple covers in a single `base64` that needs to be parsed?

Comment: My guess is that there are 2 items, so they are separated by ` / `, you need to split the string before base64 decoding.

Comment: Brilliant, that works! One last thing (even though this topic is already "solved"). I can't figure out how to make `mi.Get(StreamKind.General, 0, "Cover_Mime")`, `mi.Get(StreamKind.General, 0, "Cover_Type")`, and `mi.Get(StreamKind.General, 0, "Cover_Description"` to work. I get empty returns no matter how or in what sequence I call those functions.

Comment: `Cover_Mime` and so on are there only if in the file directly, they are not "guessed", and they are rarely in files. If you don't see them in the GUI, this is normal that you don't see them with the API.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thanks again!